# python - position textbox / plt.figtext of several images exactly below images

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, pdf, plot

I have a set of photos, for which I made labels I want to position directly below the images and save them in a pdf, as in this link https://docdro.id/4AZFIae. As you can see, some labels are far below, some intersect with the picture. I am making this pdf within the following loop. I have not figured out, how to set the position values of plt.figtext(x,y,textString...) so that textString (label) is always directly below the image. I guess x,y depend on the number of rows of textString but I did not figure out the relation

```
pdf = FPDF()

#begin of loop where I create the labels and upload the pictures
for c in range(0,15)
#...
  imshow=plt.imshow(img)
  #pdfFile.savefig(imshow)  
  plt.axis('off')
  plt.title(n_id)
  count = 0 
  textString =""
  for c in range(0,c_lab):
    textString += str(lab_out[c])
    c += 1
    textString += '\n'
  strar=['hallo', 'Das ist ein Text']
  textvar=plt.figtext(0.01, -1.0, textString, wrap=False, va='bottom', horizontalalignment='left', fontsize=12)  #textString = Labels you can see in the pdf

  plt.savefig('testplot' + str(c) +'.jpg', bbox_inches="tight")
  pdf.add_page()
  pdf.image('testplot' + str(c) +'.jpg')
  textvar.remove()  
  lab_text={}
  i+=1

pdf.output("yourfile.pdf", "F")
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you use subplots and then put your text in the bottom subplot:

```py
axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(8, 10.5))
axs[0].imshow(img)
axs[1].text(0.01, 1, textString, va='top')
```

if your text is much larger than your images, consider setting the relative heights:

```py
axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(8, 10.5), 
                   gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[1, 3]})
```